# RDLC Report - how to dynamically set the height of Tablix?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I made two Tablix which they are bound by one dataset.

[image]

Accrording Design windows, Tablix1 and tablix2 are same height.

But It's has a problem when some data of Dataset is too long.
A Tablix1's height and A Tablix2's height aren't equal.

[image]

How to dynamically set Height depend on texts in each row?
How to set Tablix1's height = tablix2's height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having two tablix with same size dynamic rows is not possible. What you could possibly do depending on your use case is to have one tablix that looks like two seperate tablix by using the designer.

You can use SQL to create a dataset that suits your needs.

```
SELECT LeftColOuter.SerialNo AS LeftSerial, LeftColOuter.Name AS LeftName, RightColOuter.SerialNo AS RightSerial, RightColOuter.Name AS RightName FROM (
    SELECT LeftCol.SerialNo, LeftCol.Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LeftCol.SerialNo) AS RowNum FROM
    (
        SELECT SerialNo as SerialNo, Name as Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SerialNo) as RowNum FROM Test
    ) AS LeftCol
    WHERE RowNum % 2 = 1
) AS LeftColOuter
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT RightCol.Name, RightCol.SerialNo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RightCol.SerialNo) AS RowNum FROM
    (
        SELECT SerialNo as SerialNo, Name as Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SerialNo) as RowNum FROM Test
    ) AS RightCol
    WHERE RowNum % 2 = 0
) AS RightColOuter ON LeftColOuter.RowNum = RightColOuter.RowNum
```

This would create the following table

[image]

Comment: Because I need to split Dataset to be Two tablix. (Two column of paper)
It write from Left to Right then Top to Buttom.
Is It impossible? What should I do?